# Expand arguments in string substitution macro

Tags: expansion, strings

Rewritten as minimum non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\textfromcase[1]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{% for the purposes of this example:
        {0}{AB} % \textfromcase[0] expands to AB
        {1}{CD} % \textfromcase[1] expands to CD
        % and many more lines of this kind.
}}

\newcommand{\EscSubstitute}[2]{\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{#1}{#2}[\x]}
\newcommand\substitute[1]{{%
    \noexpandarg% because I otherwise get weird error messages.
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{BC}{CB}[\x]% replacements for example.
    \EscSubstitute{PQ}{QP}% many more lines of this kind.
    \x}}

\newcommand{\concatenate}[1]{%
   \substitute{\@for \el:=#1\do{\textfromcase{\el}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\substitute{ABCD} = ACBD.

\concatenate{1,0} = CDAB.

\concatenate{0,1} $\neq$ ACBD!
\end{document}
```

`\concatenate{0,1}` should expand to `ACBD` but instead expands to `ABCD`.

Comment: We probably need a bit more detail here. The obvious thing to do is simply fully expand the argument to `\substitute` but you've deliberately disabled much the same idea for `\StrSubstitute` using `\noexpandarg`. That makes me suspect there is more to the arguments here than simple text. Can you give more detail? Also, at present we have to guess what packages you are using: a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be useful.

Comment: I'd probably do then entire process here just using `expl3`, by the way.

Comment: Made a minimum working example (i.e. added the first 4 and last 6 non-empty lines). `\noexpandarg` is because it gives me weird error messages otherwise. I tried using `expl3`, but couldn't get it done that way, either.

Comment: There is an important difference  between your initial snippets and the full MWE: that `\@for` part. That explains why you've used `\noexpandarg` so I can hopefully provide a solution.

Comment: No, it doesn't, the `\@for` was from my in-between attempts at finding another solution. With the `\@for`, the error message on leaving out the `\noexpandarg` is different, but in either case there is an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fully expand the argument of `\substitute` before you use this command. That can be arranged but not with a `\@for` mapping, which is non-expandable. As you are already using `xparse` I'd just write this in `expl3`. See code comments for details:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% User command taking ones comma-list argument
\NewDocumentCommand \concatenate { > { \SplitList { , } } m }
  {
    % Use an x-type expansion with an expandable argument to force
    % expansion here
    \user_substitute:x
      {
        \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \user_text_from_case:n
      }
  }
% A simple document-level wrapper around a code-level function
\NewDocumentCommand \substitute { m }
  { \user_substitute:n {#1} }
% The code-level substitution command is built to be flexible
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_substitute:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l__user_tmp_tl {#1}
      \tl_map_inline:nn
        {
          % A list of pairs for substitution: could be in a separate
          % tl or comma list depending on requirements
          { { BC } { CB } }
          { { PQ } { QP } }
        }
        { \__user_substitute_aux:nn ##1 }
    \exp_last_unbraced:NV \group_end:
    \l__user_tmp_tl
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_substitute:n { x }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_substitute_aux:nn #1#2
  { \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__user_tmp_tl {#1} {#2} }
\tl_new:N \l__user_tmp_tl
% An expandable case function to do first replacements
% Again, the list itself could be in a separate variable if required
\cs_new:Npn \user_text_from_case:n #1
  {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        { 0 } { AB }
        { 1 } { CD }
      }
  }

% For outdated expl3 installations
\cs_if_exist:NF \str_case:nn
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \str_case:nn #1#2
      { \prg_case_str:nnn {#1} {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\substitute{ABCD} = ACBD.

\concatenate{1,0} = CDAB.

\concatenate{0,1} $\neq$ ACBD!
\end{document}
```

Comment: That results in: `Undefined control sequence: \user_text_from_case:n #1->\str_case:nn`

Comment: @user66554 You have an older version of `expl3` installed. We are pretty clear that we only support the latest version, but I'll add a check for the older code.